# MongoDB: $in Operator in Sharded collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

How does $in operator works in case of sharded collection?

What will be the performance of the find query, if $in contains large amount of ObjectId that are to be searched?

Answer (score 0):

For any query, the mongos router will try to figure out if your query can be sent to a single shard (for example it limits to a particular value of shard key) or not.

If yes, the query will be sent to one shard, and whatever that shard returns will be forwarded to the application.

If no, the query will be sent to all shards, and their responses will be combined by mongos then the combined response will be returned to your application.